# I am trying to make my own Batch Game, but when I try to run the Script/Code it Instantly Closes

Tags: batch-file

Alright, so I am trying to make a batch game. I have already coded/scripted the menu. So I tried to run it to see if it works, but it instantly closes! could anyone take a look at the code/script to help me find out what I am doing wrong?

Also I am using Notepad++

```
@echo off
title Dungeon Slayer - A Text RPG

:MainMenu
cls
echo.
echo Dungeon Slayer
echo   A Text RPG
echo.
echo  Build: A1
echo.
echo 1. Play
echo.
echo 2. Settings
echo.
echo 3. Changelog
echo.
echo 4. Exit
echo.
set /p MainMenuSelection
if /p "%MainMenuSelection%" EQU "1" goto :Play
if /p "%MainMenuSelection%" EQU "2" goto :Settings
if /p "%MainMenuSelection%" EQU "3" goto :Changelog
if /p "%MainMenuSelection%" EQU "4" goto :Exit
goto :MainMenu

:Play
cls
echo.
echo Currently Gameplay Development has not been started.
echo.
pause
goto :MainMenu

:Settings
cls
echo.
echo Currently we have not made any settings.
echo.
pause
goto :MainMenu

:Changelog
cls
echo.
echo 11/16/2018
echo.
echo -A1 Build Released
echo.
pause
goto :MainMenu 

:Exit
cls
exit
```

Comment: One more thing... I am fairly new to this kind of stuff as I am a young Teenager.

Comment: Run your batch file :shudders: from cmd, not explorer. The command prompt won't close immediately after your batch file completes, so you'll see the errors.

Comment: Well I can see you didn't bother to read the help file for any of the commands you are using.  I don't know any programming language that has a `/P` option for the `IF` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using `Choice`.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "Build=A1"
Set "BDate=11/16/2018"
Set "GName=Dungeon Slayer"
Set "GDesc=A Text RPG"
Title %GName% - %GDesc%

:MainMenu
ClS
Echo=
Echo=%GName%
Echo=%GDesc%
Echo=
Echo Build: %Build%
Echo=
Echo 1. Play
Echo=
Echo 2. Settings
Echo=
Echo 3. Changelog
Echo=
Echo 4. Exit
Echo=
Choice /C 1234 /M "Which item"
If ErrorLevel 4 Exit /B
If ErrorLevel 3 GoTo ChangeLog
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo Settings

:Play
ClS
Echo=
Echo Sorry, gameplay development has not yet started.
Echo=
Timeout 3 >Nul
GoTo MainMenu

:Settings
ClS
Echo=
Echo Sorry, we are yet to create any settings.
Echo=
Timeout 3 >Nul
GoTo MainMenu

:ChangeLog
ClS
Echo=
Echo=%BDate%
Echo=
Echo -%Build% Build Released
Echo=
Timeout 3 >Nul
GoTo MainMenu
```

Comment: Thanks, my friend!